# JS: calling a function from another JS file

Tags: javascript

I want to return some values in the dda.js that have been modified in `translacao.js`. I want to return this values and execute the `dda.js` by the `translacao.js` file

```
$(document).on('click', '#trans', function () {
  var tx = parseInt($('#tx').val());
  var ty = parseInt($('#ty').val());
  translation(tx, ty);
});

function translation(tx, ty) {
  x1 = x1 + tx;
  y1 = y1 + ty;
  x2 = x2 + tx;
  y2 = y2 + ty;

  return dda(x1,y1,x2,y2);
}
```

Comment: You haven't mentioned a problem. There is nothing stopping you from calling a function defined in another file beyond making sure the file that has the function is loaded first. Also in your example you don't do anything with the returned value you in your click handler

Comment: what i want to know is how can i use the value that i returned and execute the function dda, all that executing only the function tranlation.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you always to put your JavaScript code in a `document.onload` event. It is always a good usage:

```
document.onload = function(){
   // your code
};
```

In jQuery you have a better choice:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
// your code
});
```

This way your code will always be executed when the document is fully loaded, so when all the js files are loaded.